# Redux actions typescript return type not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

So basicly I am trying to return types for a set of functions & being able to match that in my redux reducer.

Here is my attempt:

actions.ts

```
export const SET_CART_ITEMS = "SET_CART_ITEMS";
export const SET_CART_TOTALS = "SET_CART_TOTALS";

export const ADD_CART_ITEM = "ADD_CART_ITEM";
export const REMOVE_CART_ITEM = "REMOVE_CART_ITEM";

export const SET_CART_LOADING = "SET_CART_LOADING";

export function setCart(cart: Cart) {
  return {
    type: SET_CART_ITEMS,
    cart
  } as const;
}

export function setTotals(totals: CartTotal) {
  return {
    type: SET_CART_TOTALS,
    totals
  }
}

export function addCartItem(cart: Cart) {
  return {
    type: ADD_CART_ITEM,
    cart
  } as const;
}

export function removeCartItem(cart: Cart) {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
    cart
  } as const;
}

export function toggleCartLoading(loading: boolean) {
  return {
    type: SET_CART_LOADING,
    loading
  } as const;
}

export type CartActions = ReturnType<typeof setCart>| ReturnType<typeof addCartItem> | ReturnType<typeof removeCartItem> | ReturnType<typeof toggleCartLoading> | ReturnType<typeof setTotals>
```

reducer.ts

```
import { 
   CartActions,  
   ADD_CART_ITEM,
   REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
   SET_CART_ITEMS,
   SET_CART_TOTALS,
   SET_CART_LOADING 
} from '../../../actions';

export default (state: CartState = initialState, action: CartActions) : CartState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CART_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: {
          ...action.cart
        }
      }
    case REMOVE_CART_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: {
          ...action.cart
        }
      }
    case SET_CART_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: action.cart
      }
    case SET_CART_TOTALS:
      return {
        ...state,
        totals: action.totals
      }
    case SET_CART_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.loading
      }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

This does not work at all, the error i'm getting is in the reducer switch saying:

```
"Property 'cart' does not exist on type 'CartActions'.
  Property 'cart' does not exist on type '{ type: string; totals: CartTotal; }'."


Property 'loading' does not exist on type '{ readonly type: "SET_CART_ITEMS"; readonly cart: Record<string, CartItem>; } | { readonly type: "ADD_CART_ITEM"; readonly cart: Record<string, CartItem>; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }'.
  Property 'loading' does not exist on type '{ readonly type: "SET_CART_ITEMS"; readonly cart: Record<string, CartItem>; }'.ts(2339)
```

Am I missing something obvious? I would really want to not needing to type all the actions by interfaces manually.

Inspiration from https://gist.github.com/schettino/c8bf5062ef99993ce32514807ffae849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary, that each action creator return type is annotated with `as const`, so TS can discriminate your actions in the switch statement of the reducer.

In `setTotals` this const assertion seems to be missing - at least the provided code works again in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMoFEAqB9AYQEEAlfASRywFkM4BeOAIm32LL0poyYG4BYAFChIsRCnRxWhUvhwB5HEQAydRi1wyOCpar5ChI6PCRp4RACIWtFKtQbNL19rZr7h4Y%20LNwSNeQBqWDacdg5MftSBwS6hbgKChp5ippLSscryluQAcgDi4emyeJnZ%20e5CMACeYMBwBACGYowA3nANAFxw6FAAlsgA5nAAvgnVtfVNMDgQMA0ANg5tAEZdPf1Do5U1dY2wGHMwda1CcHAAZhAQazB9gwlnCFMA-F17MA9wMLMLqK%20TsBmc3mn3mEAaABMNv9lld5sAGsgEltEh5RPBzgBXZAIGC9FDdYAwd4ACiesDeUwAlHAWqc4FAiZioMhafSzuNgF0ihwuLQADTsxBTenDdqobzoZEGNFeLE4vEE1BEoG-EnfYGoSmAn7zGl0wRnRkwZmsg1nDk7bmaWI6FQYQWGi0a36i8WSj5CYYyoxieW4-GsyEQ97kI4AWzJU21MH19ONprZTsttS6ThCfMdFuFsDdDQlqU9gm9qN9GOxAYJjPDEAAbsBQxGoxSAbGk0amSz286rb5-EEM3YsxbyTA8wWJEWS0l0RcK4rWd8BgN4e9lOCoYMSWDIRsurCIPDEXGnQmu%20ae6mpDbiqULLk8sOzjvNwNxx7paXkvBOa2iJW0AYekAB9fE7ZAcB2AAeTkIHOQliSmAA%20ECwJNFlINqGCdjg9oIRDKYw2AcMUKdUCSHAzDgGw2pcOrOsG0IiNSLOcjKOg2D4KXFdGNgddd0GFi4DY9CII4nD4OVaZdVQJCEhnLwIWAc4GkxeZ4BJel0AaI4YwOHTjlpC4ri6JhliaJgRmHBoAJjf8F1QIQqT0w5jiQ7tUAAd16GAEAACzgEkbIXAA6TkT2zJ5lTgdNYj5DohQ7UTu2zM4QvS7SjifVLRy6C9UotdKQuCwMQtHRKLRLAqUUi-M6kiaJBxoBLkwtM8zQqtKMtc7LapbfKCrgIqSpQMqRVa7MqtSmqRzq682GKPkMBagr2pS1Kisy4BetmlsRuQMbcwmkZPkeOaeTkRR7RW1K1oG7NNp6zqvhkrp9rCmSKpms7ooukosnvfIbuzO7nsegydufDc93aACQpfDYvtOuAlJUtSYGBi1lkZBoAGtPimtatuRBIgA), after having added it.

You could create a generic action creator to make it more scalable and omit `as const`:

```
function createAction<T extends string, U, K extends string>(type: T, key: K, payload: U) {
  return ({
    type,
    [key]: payload
  }) as { type: T; } & { [P in K]: U }
  // need to cast, so TS doesn't return a widened index signature type
}

export function setTotals(totals: CartTotal) {
  return createAction(SET_CART_TOTALS, "totals", totals)
}
// same with the other functions
```

[Code sample in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=25&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMoFEAqB9AYQEEAlfASRywFkM4BeOAIm32LL0poyYG4BYAFChIsRCnRxWhUvhwB5HEQAydRi1wyOCpar5ChI6PCRp4RACIWtFKtQbNL19rZr7h4Y%20LNwSNeQBqWDacdg5MftSBwS6hbgKChp5ippLSscryluQAcgDi4emyeJnZ%20e5CMACeYMBwBACGYowA3nANAFxw6FAAlsgA5nAAvgnVtfVNMDgQMA0ANg5tAEZdPf1Do5U1dY2wGHMwda1CcHAAZhAQazB9gwlnCFMA-F17MA9wMLMLqK%20TsBmc3mn3mEAaABMNv9lld5sAGsgEltEh5RPBzgBXZAIGC9FDdYAwd4ACiesDeUwAlHAWqc4FAiZioMhafSzuNgF0ihwuLQADTsxBTenDdqobzoZEGNFeLE4vEE1BEoG-EnfYGoSmAn7zGl0wRnRkwZmshCMhpHIi4-HIEk8uSKFQYfnMDW-Jiu93zVBUoTDGVGMTym0EyEQ97kI4AWzJU21MH19ONpsQFqtobtThCfNdTHJME9wtgfsEAdRQYx2MzDOA0YgADdgJGY3GKQDE2zDbWTSy0wiM4q7ZFojm7HmC0WC6Xy0l0Rdq0OvhABgN4e9lOCoYMSWDIRsurCIPDEUnuym%20%20aB8BrUP7ZoMlkLLk8nm99uBkX3xsZzKQ0ur0tG9MwAHhwOBQCOZAIQldZBldABVV0AGkIJAKCYO6W4NgAPnVHYuhwV0AGtgCqLpkNdMAGiqd8ugQs8jSZPsSQNM4OR2QVuzOABtUiqgAXS6ajaK3UUaQaCU2k5QjeBGOAADJaTgHiAAU4H6OBkKEuAEJGekAHoDLgZBgGACFl2FdBXVQCA4BwOgIQgYBUGQAByeAL1ZBo4AAd16CFgFMiz%20kCkBul6AZkEtZk6k5f1A2SeBOQ7W9bQleh6QAH18ZjkBwHYQM5CBzkJYkphw7Lct7fLCuK0rwxbOtKu7HKSDygraiKnYStresmya6MWrONqOrqnrSu%20Vd1ymTd90GYa4FGmrOuAbral65Vpl1VAcISOcvEC84GkxeZ4BJel0CAhMDiApYLiuLomGWJomBGLizgaTMEzSiQhCpG7DmOHCuzOVB-JgBAAAs4BJL6hwAOk5Rj2KeZU4GzWI%20Q6IUmJq0H2MJhHiauo4PsJ1H4wJin2OJhH4dtBGC1x9jyxplFCbRuoRyCMcaBx7j2K86mKbp0ngHJmmCy6Niadp4mGZQJmRUFwm2YpjnKfRh04loAWaeF2WabFoHJYp6X2kzZXYBZzXHkkuodZ0Z19Ypw2WbOE2gLNwnvS1S3Eb923Pnt7WH2KUpn3yV3Cfd1X5YR8WffY79Bi6RXkAR1OBmDoUjpOs6Y-Y5YLWIz51eF8XkQSIA)

Answer (score 1):

With the way you implemented `CartActions`, you should always assign the type of each action to it.

for example, you should change:

```
case REMOVE_CART_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: {
      ...action.cart
    }
  }
```

to this:

```
case REMOVE_CART_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: {
      ...action.cart
    }
  } as ReturnType<typeof removeCartItem>
```

---

or you can modify your `CartActions` so type act as a separator:

```
const enum ActionTypes {
  SET_CART_ITEMS,
  SET_CART_TOTALS,
  ADD_CART_ITEM,
  REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
  SET_CART_LOADING
}



type CartActions =
  | {
      type:
        | ActionTypes.SET_CART_ITEMS
        | ActionTypes.ADD_CART_ITEM
        | ActionTypes.REMOVE_CART_ITEM;
      cart: Cart;
    }
  | {
      type: ActionTypes.SET_CART_TOTALS;
      totals: CartTotal;
    }
  | {
      type: ActionTypes.SET_CART_LOADING;
      loading: boolean;
    };

export function setCart(cart: Cart): CartActions {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SET_CART_ITEMS,
    cart
  };
}

export function setTotals(totals: CartTotal): CartActions {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SET_CART_TOTALS,
    totals
  };
}

export function addCartItem(cart: Cart): CartActions {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_CART_ITEM,
    cart
  };
}

export function removeCartItem(cart: Cart): CartActions {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
    cart
  };
}

export function toggleCartLoading(loading: boolean): CartActions {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SET_CART_LOADING,
    loading
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I assume this gist is outdated that I was taking inspiration from? https://gist.github.com/schettino/c8bf5062ef99993ce32514807ffae849#file-useuserreducer-ts-L36

Comment: Unfortunately neither of your examples works. Getting similar error